# Overwrite textdomain of plugins by default - Lost Translation

Tags: plugins, updates, translation, textdomain

Wordpress is awesome, but there is something that is driving me crazy.

Whenever a plugin or a theme is updated, all files are deleted and replaced.
So if I have custom code or a translation in one plugin, it will get lost!

I've seen some solutions suggesting to change the textdomain of the plugin to load language files from wp-content/languages, but if I write a custom function to load the *.po and *.mo from wp-content, directly in the plugin code, it will get overwritten too.

So I was wondering how I can update my plugins, without losing the translation or the custom code.

I ended up with WPML strings that do the job, by saving translation in DB, ( I'm not sure if is the way) but WPML is a very heavy plugin, and I will have to install it in all sites, which makes it difficult to maintain.

Is there any function to overwrite all textdomains of a plugin, so I can have all of the translations in wp-content/languages, without changing plugin code?

Comment: As starting point, always backup the translations you do. Second, send them to the plugin/theme author, high probability of getting them included in the next releases. Related: [\[1\]](http://www.geertdedeckere.be/article/loading-wordpress-language-files-the-right-way) + [\[2\]](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=load_textdomain+is%3Aanswer) + [\[3\]](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18960).

Comment: custom translation.

Comment: some plugins like woocommerce are enabled to read wp-content/languages/woocommerce/ mo and po files default so translations won't be overwiten.

Also since 3.5 translation of themes by default  from wp-content, but plugins not yet.
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18200#comment:43

Comment: Would the core of your Question be: *"How to prevent themes/plugins that don't work with `/wp-content/languages` to load their language files and force them to load my own files"* ?

Comment: well done! sure it is

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [patch for 3.5](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/18200/no_plugin_overwrite.patch) to use this with plugins.
Use `wp-content/languages/plugins/textdomain-pt_BR.po`

Apply this via SSH with: `patch -p1 < no_plugin_overwrite.patch`
Hopefully its gonna be released in 3.6.

> #### [Ticket #18200 (new task (blessed))](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18200)
>
> Implement language packs for core, plugins, and themes.

Comment: Eu sabia! André com acento no `é` ;) - Great to know this is a core candidate, I like this string in the patch: ***`'Some of your language files need updating, Sit tight for a few more seconds while we update them as well.'`***